# Print specific names from two .txt files

Tags: python-3.x

the following problem was coming up during my homework. First of all the code:

```
def read_docs(filename):
        with open(filename) as fh:
            return [x.strip() for x in fh.readlines()]

txt_file_1984 = read_docs('forenames_1984.txt')
txt_file_2015 = read_docs('fornames_2015.txt')
txt_file_all = txt_file_1984 + txt_file_2015

print('names, which were only popular in 1984:', end=' ')
for i in range(0, len(txt_file_1984)):
   print(txt_file_1984[i].replace("\n", ",  "), end=', ')

    print('\n')
print('names, which were only popular in 2015:', end=' ')
for j in range(0, len(txt_file_2015)):
    print(txt_file_2015[j].replace("\n", ",  "), end=', ')

print('\n')
print('popular names in both years:', end=' ')
for k in range(0, len(txt_file_all)):
    print(txt_file_all[k].replace("\n", ",  "), end=', ')
```

That Code here is giving the following Output:

```
names, which were only popular in 1984: Markus, Claudia, Thomas, . . . 

names, which were only popular in 2015: Lukas, Anna, David, . . .  

popular names in both years: Markus, Elisabeth, . . .
```

In general I am satisfied with that Output, but there is something missing here, because you can see that this Code prints all names from the file "txt_file_1984", all names from the file "txt_file_2015" and it prints all names from both textfiles together. But that is not exactly what I want.

Here is in detail what I want to have:

I want to print out all popular names from 1984 **which were not popular in 2015**.

In the next block I want to print all names which were popular in 2015, **but not in 1984**. (So the same as above but vice versa)

The Last Block should show an Output in which there are only the names, which were **popular in 1984 AND 2015**, only this names should be printed.

Hope you understand what I mean. Am I on the right path here? I need some help, thanks.

By the way, it is not allowed to import libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the printing part down. What is missing is to identify the elements in the both lists which fulfill your current requirement.
What can help you are list comprehensions, with which you can build the new lists.

```
# popular only in 1984
popular_only_84 = [x for x in txt_file_1984 if x not in txt_file_2015]

# popular only in 2015
popular_only_15 = [x for x in txt_file_2015 if x not in txt_file_1984]

# popular in both
popular_both = [x for x in txt_file_2015 if x in txt_file_1984]
```

Those lists now contain the elements you want and you can simple print them with:

```
for name in popular_only_84:    # run through all elements in the list for 84
     # your printing code
```

So in your code you could print one list with:

```
print('names, which were only popular in 1984:', end=' ')
for name in popular_only_84:
    print(name.replace("\n", ",  "), end=', ')
```